# Session not register in jquery background

Tags: php, javascript, jquery-mobile

I have a small script that saves (save.php) the data to my mysql db. but its trigered by jquery mobile  event handler. I can use the POST to send data to my save.php and works perfectly. But I have to save some values to session for my other forms and security. 
Here is my javascript code.

form.php:

```
<? 
session_start();
$_SESSION[ClientID]='1007';
?>
<script>
    $(document).on("pageinit","#my-page",function(){
      $("form").tap(function(){ 
           $.post("save.php",
           $("#myform").serialize()
           );
      });
    });
    </script>
```

this code simply trigers the save.php and sends the value using post method in form. 
I tryed to send user-data($_SESSION) using hidden fields. But this form uses 5 steps I have to store userdata via session. somehow I cannot get session data outside this form.php

save.php

```
<? 
session_start();
$SQL2="UPDATE  `Reports` SET  
`TotalAmount` =  '$_POST[TotalAmount]' Where `ClientID`='$_SESSION[ClientID]'";
$DB->ExecuteQuery ($SQL2,$connection); // My SQL Execute Class
?>
```

I echo the $SQL2 it goes like 
$SQL2="UPDATE  `Reports` SET`TotalAmount` =  '1550' Where `ClientID`=''";

So basicly problem is session have no value in save.php
Please help me with this.

Comment: it should be $_SESSION["ClientID"]='1007'; --- with quotes.. other wise PHP will think ClientID is ome constant..

Answer (score 0):

Try this, in the first block change your session to this...

```
$_SESSION['ClientID'] = '1007';
```

and in the second block change the query to say this...

```
$SQL2 = "UPDATE 'Reports' SET 'TotalAmount' = '$_POST[TotalAmount]' WHERE 'ClientID'='".$_SESSION['ClientID']."'";
```

and let me know how you get on with that

Comment: Thank you but not worked. I am sure its not about the writing

Comment: Have you tried a different browser? I've had problems with sessions before on certain browsers when it is not on a server and working from localhost

Comment: Thank You daniel. Actually its not about the browser. I can get the session data in form.php but not in save.php
please note that save.php trigered in background

Comment: Oh so it's just no carrying the session from page to page? 

The two things I can think of are the following... either the session is being stored AFTER the header is sent, or you are using session_destroy() somewhere which is cancelling all sessions out

Comment: I'm not using the session_destroy. Good point about the header. Besides I keep getting this error. 
Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by...
Any ideas?

Comment: Try this, you have <?php session_start(); try placing each on a different line... I'll edit your code, it sounds a bit intuitive but PHP is a right funny thing when it comes to this